# Python: erro unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tupla

Oi, estou com um problema com uma função em Python, que envolve um tuplo de tuplos. Ao executar esta função assembleia chamando o tuplo de tuplos votacoes:

```
votacoes = (
    (0, 15729, 220408, 1297, 0, 3040, 993, 0, 1354, 1046, 0, 3284, 99652, 19327, 0), 
    (0, 19000, 23173, 255, 0, 532, 201, 0, 306, 232, 0, 1980, 22307, 3890, 0), 
    (0, 23731, 244971, 1959, 0, 2710, 1465, 0, 1094, 1114, 0, 4264, 159476, 20488, 0), 
    (0, 1956, 47716, 282, 0, 0, 175, 0, 165, 247, 0, 417, 19728, 1732, 0),
    (0, 5384, 52325, 403, 0, 770, 543, 0, 428, 0, 0, 1454, 38317, 4609, 0), 
    (0, 14138, 113419, 662, 0, 2535, 600, 0, 591, 557, 0, 2014, 66199, 13034, 0),
    (0, 18967, 31260, 237, 0, 649, 216, 0, 168, 207, 0, 1810, 25010, 4225, 0),
    (0, 17255, 99745, 2076, 0, 3285, 0, 0, 1069, 700, 0, 3160, 46082, 16347, 0),
    (0, 3299, 53450, 251, 0, 520, 199, 0, 178, 191, 0, 755, 26263, 3114, 0),
    (0, 12351, 148762, 977, 0, 3029, 633, 0, 595, 453, 0, 2502, 51518, 0, 0), 
    (0, 111661, 560365, 4135, 0, 16913, 2410, 0, 5897, 4270, 0, 14419, 322034, 66874, 0),
    (0, 7910, 26257, 176, 0, 333, 162, 0, 151, 135, 0, 1031, 19963, 2753, 0), 
    (0, 61832, 488402, 2413, 0, 9072, 3386, 0, 1551, 1525, 0, 9640, 318113, 51002, 0),
    (0, 21347, 118028, 1454, 0, 2220, 692, 0, 832, 726, 0, 3413, 61194, 13712, 0),
    (0, 82159, 156444, 1682, 0, 6282, 1133, 0, 1595, 847, 0, 0, 112764, 29667, 0),
    (0, 6648, 76961, 384, 0, 926, 0, 0, 213, 331, 0, 1473, 35327, 5928, 0), 
    (0, 3656, 71840, 304, 0, 617, 254, 0, 147, 574, 0, 675, 34825, 2784, 0), 
    (0, 5810, 123184, 696, 0, 1229, 465, 0, 266, 626, 0, 1456, 54107, 5786, 0),
    (0, 2288, 53518, 314, 0, 756, 293, 0, 219, 271, 0, 669, 23189, 3965, 0),
    (0, 5096, 87597, 2560, 0, 2385, 2992, 0, 617, 538, 0, 1967, 20360, 5568, 0),
    (0, 803, 6306, 101, 0, 192, 83, 0, 48, 50, 0, 132, 7205, 602, 0),
    (0, 127, 8938, 87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 47, 0,52, 2714, 165, 0)
)

def assembleia(t):
    lst_votos = list (t)
    lst = []
    for e in t:
        lst = lst + [0]    

    n = (16, 3, 19, 3, 4, 9, 3, 9, 4, 10, 47, 2, 39, 9, 18, 6, 5, 9, 5, 6, 2, 2)
    lst_mand = list (n)
    lstm = []
    for i in n:
        lstm = lstm + [0]        

    for z in n:
        while z > 0:
            maior = lst_votos[0]
            for i in range(0, len(lst_votos)):
                if lst_votos[i] > maior:
                    maior = lst_votos[i]         

            for j in range(0, len(lst_votos)):
                if maior == lst_votos[j]:
                    p = j     

            lst[p] = lst[p] + 1

            lst_votos = lst_votos[:p] + [(lst_votos[p] * lst[p]) / (lst[p] +1)] + lst_votos[p+1:]

            z = (z - 1)

    return tuple(lst)
```

O erro que dá é:

```
line 61, in <module>
    lst_votos = lst_votos[:p] + [(lst_votos[p] * lst[p]) / (lst[p] +1)] + lst_votos[p+1:]
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Eu consigo perceber o porquê desse erro, mas não estou a conseguir de forma alguma dar a volta e por a funcionar.... Consigo por a funcionar se fizer um a um, agora chamando assim o tuplo, quebrou...
A ideia é que depois é retornado um tuplo com os resultados da distribuição das votações (depois terei que somar esse retorno, mas ainda não o coloquei no código).

Comment: hmm, ta meio dificil de responder a sua pergunta. O erro você já percebeu: `list_votos[p]` é uma tupla e `lst[p]` é um inteiro então `list_votos[p] * lst[p]` é uma tupla e tuplas não podem ser o numerador de uma divisão. Mas não sei muito bem o que você quer que o programa realmente faça para poder sugerir uma correção.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O que pretendo é que o programa faça um cálculo segundo o método D'Hondt. Cada número dentro da lista `n` é um número de lugares a ser distribuído conforme a votação que está presente no tuplo correspondente dentro de `votacoes`.

Comment: O output seria um tuplo de tuplos com o resultado da distribuição de lugares. E consigo por a funcionar se eu der cada elemento individualmente, assim:
`assembleia(16, (0, 15729, 220408, 1297, 0, 3040, 993, 0, 1354, 1046, 0, 3284, 99652, 19327, 0))` consigo o retorno esperado `(0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um problema no seu código é que você está manipulando tuplas, quando, na verdade, gostaria de manipular números inteiros que fazem parte dessas tuplas.

O problema se resume a acessar dados em matrizes, ou seja, tuplas e listas multidimensionais.

Por exemplo, quando inicia sua função, você está apenas transformando a tupla de fora em uma lista, e não as tuplas internas:

```
def assembleia(t):
    lst_votos = list(t)
```

Nesse caso, você apenas estaria fazendo com que isso:

```
((10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60))
```

Se tornasse isso:

```
[(10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60)]
```

Suponha afinal que:

```
lst_votos = [(10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60)]
```

Mais adiante, quando você faz `maior = lst_votos[0]`, está passando a primeira tupla como valor para `maior`. O que acarretará em:

```
>>> print(maior)
(10, 20, 30)
```

Nesse contexto, você quer atribuir o primeiro valor dessa tupla para a variável `maior`, então você deve passar o primeiro elemento da primeira tupla:

```
>>> lst_votos = [(10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60)]
>>> maior = lst_votos[0][0]
>>> print(maior)
10
```

Se você tivesse três dimensões:

```
>>> exemplo = [((1, 2), 20, 30), (40, 50, 60)]
>>> print(exemplo[0][0][0])
1
```

Para corrigir isso, terá que mudar vários pontos de seu código. Te aconselho a dividir o problema em partes menores, dentro de funções:

- Uma função que resolve a alocação de mandatos relativos a uma tupla, recebendo como argumentos o número de mandatos e uma tupla de votacao, como assembleia();
- Outra função que recebe como argumentos a tupla de mandatos e a tupla de tuplas de votacoes, que leva a um loop chamando a função assembleia() n vezes.

Assim você não terá que acessar dados multidimensionais e deixará seu código mais claro.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta. Realmente ajudou :)